# simplexml_load_file(): http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather= invalid element name

Tags: php, yii-extensions

I am getting this error on my website built in Yii framework. I used Yii extension **weatherwidget** to display weather info on my page. Does any body know whats causing this problem. Here is the extension code on my page.

```
<?php  
 $location = 63376;
  $this->widget('application.components.weather.GoogleWeatherAPI', array('location'=>$location)); ?>
```